# I have an enigma in my method , VALIDATE and INSERT code

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, sqlcommand

This is my INSERT code :

```
Dim _cmd as new SQLCommand()

Private Sub _btAdd_ANA_GRUPO_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _btAdd_ANA_GRUPO.Click

    _resultCMD = 0

    'Por cada linha da grid analises
    For Ro = 0 To DataGrid_AnaEXT.Rows.Count - 1

        If DataGrid_AnaEXT.Rows(Ro).Cells("Selected").Value = 1 Then

            _cmd.Parameters.Clear() ' here i clear because i use the _cmd other sections

           '**enigma**'
           _query = "INSERT into dbo.tbl_ENC_GRUPO_ANA_LINHA VALUES( @idG, @idAna, @sigla, @nomeA, @_ck )"  / If i put the query string here ,the INSERT does nothing

            'Dim _cmd As New SqlCommand - I tried to declare here but same problem

            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@idG", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _dgvGruposA.CurrentRow.Cells("ID_GRUPO_ANA").Value
            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@idAna", SqlDbType.Char).Value = Trim(DataGrid_AnaEXT.Rows(Ro).Cells("ANA_ID").Value.ToString())
            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@sigla", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Trim(DataGrid_AnaEXT.Rows(Ro).Cells("ANA_SIGLA").Value.ToString())
            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@nomeA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _selectAnaNome(Trim(DataGrid_AnaEXT.Rows(Ro).Cells("ANA_ID").Value.ToString()))
            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@_ck", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = DataGrid_AnaEXT.Rows(Ro).Cells("Selected").Value

            'Here i check if and ID exist in destination table "_checkAnaNoGrupo" , to not duplicate


            If _checkAnaNoGrupo(_dgvGruposA.CurrentRow.Cells("ID_GRUPO_ANA").Value, (DataGrid_AnaEXT.Rows(Ro).Cells("ANA_ID").Value.ToString)) = False Then

                _query = "INSERT into dbo.tbl_ENC_GRUPO_ANA_LINHA VALUES( @idG, @idAna, @sigla, @nomeA, @_ck )"


                _cmd.Connection = _con.connect
                _cmd.CommandText = _query
                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Try
                    _con.connect.Open()
                    _resultCMD = _resultCMD + _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    _con.connect.Close()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    _con.connect.Close()
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro Linha : " & ex.Message & " !")

                End Try

            End If

        End If
    Next

    If _resultCMD > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Adicionou : " & _resultCMD _
                        & " análises ao Grupo : " & _dgvGruposA.CurrentRow.Cells("NOME_G").Value & " !")
    End If

    _selectAnaLinhaG(CInt(_dgvGruposA.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value))

End sub
```

Here is the function that validate if exist -- It works Ok

```
Public Function _checkAnaNoGrupo(ByVal _grupoA As Integer, ByVal _codAna As String) As Boolean

    _tabCheckAnaNoGrupo() 

    Dim _ck As Boolean = False

    For Each _tRow As DataRow In _tabCheckAnaNoGrupo.Rows
        If _tRow("FK_ID_GRUPO_ANA").ToString.Contains(_grupoA) And _tRow("ID_ANA").ToString.Contains(_codAna) Then
            _ck = True
        Else
            _ck = False
        End If
    Next

    Return _ck

End Function
```

Here i get the data from SQL table into a DataTable:

```
 Public Function _tabCheckAnaNoGrupo() As DataTable

    Dim _tabCKana As New DataTable

    _query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_ENC_GRUPO_ANA_LINHA"

    _adapt.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(_query, _con.connect)

    _adapt.Fill(_tabCKana)

    Return _tabCKana

End Function
```

My Problem is :
If i run the code like this work fine the INSERT statment, but duplicate Lines.

But if i run the code with _query placed in '**enigma**'(See UP), the INSERT does nothing . NO ERROR - NOTHING

I hope you can help me, may be a stupid mistake or not but already tried several ways, and the result is always the same

Comment: You may want to put the duplicate check into the insert query itself, maybe use a stored procedure? Also you seem to be using a lot of global variables which can cause trouble that is hard to debug.

Comment: ok, i will try not to use global variables

Answer (score 0):

Ok! i found the problem and i fixit.

It was in my function that check if exist

```
Public Function _checkAnaNoGrupo(ByVal _grupoA As Integer, ByVal _codAna As String) As Boolean

    _tabCheckAnaNoGrupo()

    Dim _ck As Boolean = False

    For Each _tRow As DataRow In _tabCheckAnaNoGrupo.Rows
        If _tRow("FK_ID_GRUPO_ANA").ToString.Contains(_grupoA) And _tRow("ID_ANA").ToString.Contains(_codAna) Then
**ck = True**

**Return _ck**

**Exit Function**

'i exit the function when he found a match, else will do the for , and the _ck value will be always false.
'So when find the first match exit the function and return TRUE

        Else
            _ck = False
        End If
    Next

    Return _ck

End Function
```

My ENIGMA is SOLVED